# AudioKit How To Dispose or Reuse AKNodeRecorder

Tags: ios, audiokit

In my app I give the user options to create multiple recordings which will have different names.

I use the following to record:

```
let tape = try AKAudioFile.init(forWriting: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: path), settings: [AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC, AVSampleRateKey: 44100, AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2, AVEncoderBitRateKey: 192000, AVEncoderAudioQualityKey:AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue])
let recorder = try AKNodeRecorder(node: masterMixer, file: tape)

try recorder.record()

// Some time later
recorder.stop()
```

Everything works fine, I get the recorded audio and I can play it and hear music but here are my requirements. This works for one recording. Now I need to record another recording.

How do I go by this? Do I create another AKNodeRecorder and bind it just like this again? If this is the case wouldnt binding it all the time cause memory leaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've recorded an audio file with AKNodeRecorder, you can reuse it. Just reset it before recording again:

```
func startRecordingAudio() {
    do {
        try self.recorder?.reset()
        try recorder?.record()
    } catch {
        print("Error starting audio recording")
    }
}
```

This will save the recording to the same file. Therefore to preserve each recording, you should move the recorded file to a final destination after you've finished each recording.

```
func stopRecording() {
    recorder?.stop()
    if let recordedURL = recorder?.audioFile?.url {
        let uuid = NSUUID().uuidString
        let destinationPath = NSTemporaryDirectory() + "/" + uuid + ".caf"
        let destinationURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        do {
            try fileManager.moveItem(at: recordedURL, to: destinationURL)
        } catch {
            print("Could not copy file")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to record to a different file after I stop recording, in this code audio is written to the same file

Comment: Copying item would take lots of time if the recording is huge, I need to move the file, can u try that?

Comment: How do we reset the file of the recorder node after we move it?

Comment: I'm not sure that's necessary. Do you mean the file is being appended?

Comment: So here we moved the file that was held by the recorder node. On the next record when it tries to record a file wouldn't it crash because there is no file to write to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230336/discussion-between-vindur-and-cs-guy).

Comment: I guess it’s not needed to stop the engine?

Comment: @NatSerrano no, it shouldn't be necessary to stop the engine